# How do I broadcast a 2D array to all processes such that it can be accessed by a function in each rank?

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

I am totally new to MPI, therefore, could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong in the following code? I have constructed this code basing on an answer that I found on stackoverflow, so I just modified it a little to suit my needs. The problem I am facing is that a 2D array "A" created in process 0 cannot be seen by the other processes of rank 1,2, and 3 (I have only four processors). That is, when a process wants to use this matrix "A" in a function matrix_element(), i.e. (the place where this occurs is indicated by stars *)

```
          cc[m][n]=matrix_element(m,n,x,ngauher,A)
```

called by a process of rank higher than 0, the program terminates with a segmentation fault. Only the root process 0 is able to use this array to produce subarrays cc[m][n] inside each process. I have tried to broadcast the 2D array "A" to all processes using

```
          for(m=0;m<MAX_M;m++) {
           MPI_Bcast(A[m],MAX_M,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
          }
```

so that it can be used by each process, but the code terminates then even earlier with an error having to do with MPI_Barrier called later on in the code. I just want to know how to broadcast "A" to all processes correctly and if there is anything wrong with the call of "A" inside the matrix_element() function to be used by all processes. Anyways, the code follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "nrutil.h"
#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))

double x[1000],w[1000];
double result,global_result;
double **A,**c,**cc;
long nrl,nrh,ncl,nch;
int i,j,MAX_M,n,m,k;
int mx,my,mz,nx,ny,nz;
int ngauher;
int lstart,lend,id,p,num_elements;
int count;


FILE *ingau,*inc,*mdat,*outptr_A;
FILE *globalarrayptr=NULL;
FILE *globalarrayptr2=NULL;
FILE *localarrayptr=NULL;
char *globalarray;
char *localarray;

int malloc2d(double ***array, int n, int m);
double **dmatrix(long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
double matrix_element(int m, int n, double **A);
double hermitef(double u, int m);
double calculate_c(int m,int n, double *x, double *w, int ngauher);
double *h;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  const int MAX_M=10;
  const int procMAX_M=2;
  const int ngauher=20;
  int i,j,k,id,p,disp;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&id);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&p);

  if((localarrayptr = fopen("a.dat","w")) == NULL) {
   fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file a.dat\n");
    exit(1);
  }


  if(id == 0) {   
   if((ingau = fopen("gauspnts.dat","r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file gauspnts.dat");
     exit(1);
     }

  if((globalarrayptr = fopen("c.dat","w")) == NULL) {
   fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file c.dat\n");
    exit(1);
     }   

   printf(" opened files \n");

   h = (double *)calloc(MAX_M,sizeof(double));   

   nrl=0;
    nrh=MAX_M;
     ncl=0;
      nch=MAX_M;

   malloc2d(&c,MAX_M,MAX_M);
    malloc2d(&A,MAX_M,MAX_M);

  for(i=0;i<nrh;i++) {
   for(j=0;j<nch;j++) {
     c[i][j]=0.0;
      fprintf(globalarrayptr," %g ",c[i][j]);
     }
    fprintf(globalarrayptr,"\n");
   }

   for(k=0;k<ngauher;k++) {
    fscanf(ingau," %lf   %lf \n",&x[k],&w[k]);
     printf("  %g    %g   \n",x[k],w[k]);
    }

//    MPI_Bcast(x,ngauher,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);  // doesn't work
//     MPI_Bcast(w,ngauher,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD); // doesn't work

/* The problematic array is created right here in rank 0*/

   for(m=0;m<MAX_M;m++) {      
    for(n=0;n<MAX_M;n++) {
     A[m][n]=calculate_c(m,n,x,w,ngauher);
      printf(" rank=%d  A[%d][%d] =  %g \n",i,m,n,A[m][n]);
      } 
     }          
   }

  for(m=0;m<MAX_M;m++) {
   MPI_Bcast(A[m],MAX_M,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);   // doesn't work and
                                                        // causes a seg fault
   }


  nrl=0;
   nrh=MAX_M/procMAX_M;
    ncl=0;
     nch=MAX_M/procMAX_M;

   malloc2d(&cc,MAX_M/procMAX_M,MAX_M/procMAX_M);

  int sizes[2] = {MAX_M,MAX_M};
  int subsizes[2] = {MAX_M/procMAX_M,MAX_M/procMAX_M};
  int starts[2] = {0,0};

  MPI_Datatype type, subarrtype;
   MPI_Type_create_subarray(2,sizes,subsizes,starts,MPI_ORDER_C,MPI_DOUBLE,&type);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(type,0,MAX_M/procMAX_M*sizeof(double),&subarrtype);
     MPI_Type_commit(&subarrtype);

  double *globalptr=NULL;
  if(id == 0) globalptr=&(c[0][0]);

  int sendcounts[procMAX_M*procMAX_M];
  int displs[procMAX_M*procMAX_M];

   if(id == 0) {
    for(i=0; i<procMAX_M*procMAX_M;i++) sendcounts[i] = 1;
     disp = 0;
      for(i=0;i<procMAX_M;i++) {
       for (j=0; j<procMAX_M; j++) {
        displs[i*procMAX_M+j] = disp;
        disp += 1;
       }
      disp += ((MAX_M/procMAX_M)-1)*procMAX_M;
     }
    }  

  if (id == 0) {
   for(i=0; i<procMAX_M*procMAX_M; i++) sendcounts[i] = 1;
    disp = 0;
     for(i=0; i<procMAX_M; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<procMAX_M; j++) {
       displs[i*procMAX_M+j] = disp;
       disp += 1;
      }
     disp += ((MAX_M/procMAX_M)-1)*procMAX_M;
    }
   }
    MPI_Scatterv(globalptr,sendcounts,displs,subarrtype,&(cc[0][0]),
     MAX_M*MAX_M/(procMAX_M*procMAX_M),
     MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  /* all processors print their local data */     
 for(i=0;i<p;i++) {
  if(id == i) {
   printf("Local process on rank %d is:\n", id);
    for(m=0;m<MAX_M/procMAX_M;m++) {
     putchar('|');
      for (n=0; n<MAX_M/procMAX_M;n++) {
//         if(id == 0) { j=m; k=n; }
//          if(id == 1) { j=m+procMAX_M-1; k=n; }
//           if(id == 2) {j=m; k=n+procMAX_M-1; }
 //           if(id == 3) {j=m+procMAX_M-1; k=n+procMAX_M-1; }
 /* ************************************************************************* */
       cc[m][n]=matrix_element(m,n,A);      // THE PROBLEM WITH "A" ARISES HERE!!
 /* ************************************************************************* */
        printf(" cc[%d][%d] =  %g   id = %d\n",m,n,cc[m][n],id);
           }
         printf("|\n");
        }
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

   /* it all goes back to process 0 */
  MPI_Gatherv(&(cc[0][0]),MAX_M*MAX_M/(procMAX_M*procMAX_M),MPI_DOUBLE,
             globalptr,sendcounts,displs,subarrtype,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

 /* don't need the local data anymore */


 /* or the MPI data type */
MPI_Type_free(&subarrtype);

    if (id == 0) {
     if((globalarrayptr2 = fopen("B.dat","w")) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file B.dat\n");
       exit(1);
       }
       for(i=0;i<MAX_M;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<MAX_M;j++) {
         fprintf(globalarrayptr2," %g ",c[i][j]);
        }
       fprintf(globalarrayptr2,"\n");
      }

    }

   MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
 }



int malloc2d(double ***array, int n, int m) {
   double *p;

    /* allocate the n*m contiguous items */
    p = (double *)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));
    if (!p) return -1;

    /* allocate the row pointers into the memory */
    (*array) = (double **)malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
    if (!(*array)) {
       free(p);
   return -1;
    }

    /* set up the pointers into the contiguous memory */
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       (*array)[i] = &(p[i*m]);

    return 0;
}


double calculate_c(int m, int n, double *x, double *w, int ngauher) {
double result=0;
   int i;

 for(i=0;i<ngauher;i++) {
 result+=w[i]*exp(-SQR(x[i]))*SQR(hermitef(x[i],m)*hermitef(x[i],n));
}

 return(result);
}

double hermitef(double u, int m) {
  int j;
   double x,pi;
     pi=acos(-1.);
     x=u;
     h[0]=1./pow(pi,0.25);
     h[1]=sqrt(2.)*x/pow(pi,0.25);

     for(j=2;j<m+1;j++) {
      h[j] = sqrt(2./(double)j)*x*h[j-1]-sqrt((double)(j-1)/((double)j))*h[j-2];
     }
     return(h[m]);
}


double matrix_element(int m, int n, double **A) {
   result=0.;
 /* In this function, A is seen only by the root process ?? */

   for(mx=0;mx<=m;mx++) {
    for(my=0;my<=m;my++) {
     for(mz=0;mz<=m;mz++) {
      for(nx=0;nx<=n;nx++) {
   for(ny=0;ny<=n;ny++) {
    for(nz=0;nz<=n;nz++) {
         if(((mx+my+mz == m) && (nx+ny+nz == n))) {
      result+=A[mx][nx]*A[my][ny]*A[mz][nz];
     }
    }
   }
      }
     }
    }
   }       

  return(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `MPI_Bcast()` you array to every process, your array should be allocated `size` times, one for each process. Allocating on rank 0 is not enough. The problem is :

```
 if(id==0){
 ...
 malloc2d(&A,MAX_M,MAX_M);
 ...
 }
```

Try to get the `malloc2d(&A,MAX_M,MAX_M);` out of this test and the `MPI_Bcast()` will work fine.

Notice that since you allocated your 2D array to have values contiguous in memory, you can use

```
 MPI_Bcast(A[0],MAX_M*MAX_M,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Bye,

Comment: When I placed malloc2d() outside the if condition as you suggested, the program worked. However, MPI_Bcast() for some or the other reason was still making problems in connection to MPI_Barrier(), but right now it is no biggy. All processes were able to access the 2D A matrix after I placed it outside the if statement and I am kind of surprised by this (may be because I am a beginner). But your answer helped me a lot.